# Looking for a jQuery plugin : sort of bar rating

Tags: jquery, plugins, rating

i own a website where users can vote/rate things and i want to improve the poor inputbox (from 1 to 10) to improve visual rendering.

**I was thinking of a bar, which have 10 ' | ' you can move the cursor from one to ten**  (it doesn't have to be AJAX because the rating is only added at the end of the form)

I'm sure you already seend this king of thing but i actually can't find any plugin of it.

Any ideas please ?

**PS: i don't want standars STARS rating, already using it, thanks ;)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like to say "Why didn't you Google that?", but there are tones of it out there... http://www.google.pl/search?hl=pl&q=jquery+rating+plugin&btnG=Szukaj+w+Google&lr=

Just raplace star icons into bar icons.

### Edit (according to your comment)

I just didn't get your question. I think that [jQuery UI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#rangemin) is what you're looking for.

Comment: and how i'm supposed to know that a STAR rating is the same than a BAR rating with a tick you can move from 0 to 10 with STEPS ? For me it's not, I googled THE SAME request as yours just before posting here and i didn't find any tracks of it.

Comment: What i want to find is similar to that  : http://www.gameservercheck.de/compare/

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're really looking for a slider control. Maybe this is what you're looking for:
[Stepped Slider in jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#steps)

Answer (score 0):

I developed a rating plugin, that besides stars also supports bars and other stuff:

Download it here: http://rateit.codeplex.com
And see the examples here: http://www.radioactivethinking.com/rateit/example/example.htm (see example 7b for an alternative rating style.